# Ubuntu 18.04; black screen after 20 seconds before login

Tags: 18.04

I have reviewed all questions regarding black screen on Ubuntu 18.04.  My problem is, after rebooting or power up, if I don't login within 20 seconds or less, my screen goes black.  What do I have to do so that when the Login screen comes up, it stays on until I login? #18.04

Comment: I am using a HP LT Pavilion dm4